# Создание будильника

Tags: objective-c, ios8

Нужно создать массив с выделенными днями для будильника.
Есть 7 ячеек.

Код для выделения и отмены ячеек

```
- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath{
    UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:indexPath];
        cell.accessoryType = UITableViewCellAccessoryCheckmark;
}

- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didDeselectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath{
    UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:indexPath];
    cell.accessoryType = UITableViewCellAccessoryNone;
     NSLog(@"%i""1",(int)cell.tag);
}
```

Как мне получить index ячейки и записать в массив?

Я так полагаю нужно еще и передать значение этому индеку с массива названий дней

```
NSArray *dayNames = [NSArray arrayWithObjects:@"Su",@"Mo",@"Tu",@"We",@"Th",@"Fr",@"Sa", nil];
```

и отформатировать в время что бы будильник понял что это день

Comment: можете конкретно сказать, что у вас не получается, а то судя по вопросу вам надо чтоб половину приложения написали

Comment: Ну половину это громко сказано может советом помочь,
Вопрос:
как получить индекс ячейки и записать в массив

Comment: получить индекс можно через indexPath.row записать в массив (при условии, что массив mutable) [array addObject:[NSNumber numberWithInt:indexPath.row]]; -пишу с телефона тогут быть ошибки